# android подключение библиотеки

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, такая проблема. В приложении необходимо получать время с выбранного ntp сервера. Решил использовать для этого библиотеку TrueTime https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android. Подключил все, как указано. При отладке пишет, что исходник не соответствует байткоду. Перехожу в своем проекте в класс TrueTime он там пишет Decompiled .class file, bytecode version 51.0 (java 7), при этом предлагает скачать источник, по нажатии видим сообщение в окне запуска следующего характера

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:DownloadSources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/tmp/ijinit.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources'.
   > Could not find com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-2.2:sources.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/pluto/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.pom
         file:/home/pluto/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.jar
         file:/home/pluto/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.pom
         file:/home/pluto/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.jar
         file:/home/pluto/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.pom
         file:/home/pluto/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.jar
         https://jitpack.io/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.pom
         https://jitpack.io/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.jar
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/instacart/truetime-android/library-2.2/sources/library-2.2-sources.jar
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
2:53:41 AM: Task execution finished 'DownloadSources'.
```

Подскажите, что здесь происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Это значит что автор не загрузил исходники в репозиторий. Чтобы у вас заработала работа с исходным кодом, скорее всего надо скачать нужную версию (например с github https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android/releases и добавить ее как библиотеку https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html

Посмотрите также как это выглядит https://stackoverflow.com/a/38413439/5892568

Comment: когда подключаешь проект с гит, среда разработки разве не переводит их в байткод самостоятельно?

Comment: При деккомпиляции в зависимости от настроек компиляции может происходить обфусцирование переменных, нет комментариев и другой информации из исходного файла.